# Why isn't my CustomCell class displaying properly?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, custom-cell

Hey all, I'm trying to create a business finder style app and was hoping to create a custom cell to display some information to the user. I've got the cell to display all the information I'm trying to give, but the format is off. Here is the code I'm using to create the cell.

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellView" owner:self options:nil];

#ifdef __IPHONE_2_1
        cell = (CustomCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
#else
        cell = (CustomCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:1];
#endif
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    NSDictionary *dict = [rows objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    cell.bizNameLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
    cell.addressLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"address"];

    NSMutableString *detailed = [NSMutableString string];
    [detailed appendString:[dict objectForKey:@"distance"]];
    [detailed appendString:@"mi"];
    cell.mileageLabel.text = detailed;

    // determine the rating for the business
    NSString *icontype = [dict objectForKey:@"rating"];
    NSInteger rating = [icontype intValue];
    UIImage *image;
    // variable to change the color of the cell's background
    UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];

    // switch statement to determine the rating image to be displayed
    switch (rating) {
        case 1:
        {
            image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
            bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor]; 
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"];
            bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor]; 
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"];
            //bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; 
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }

    [cell.ratingImage setImage:image];
    cell.backgroundView = bg;
    [bg release];


#ifdef __IPHONE_3_0
    cell.accessoryType =  UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
#endif

    return cell;
}
```

I then created the layout in IB to look like this..

(First 2 issues have been resolved, I was using the wrong image variable to display the image)

And when selected, you can tell things are out of whack

![enter image description here][3]

In IB I have the dimensions of the cell set at 320wide by 80high, and under the indentity tab, I've changed the class to CustomClass. I'm sure I'm overlooking something trivial, but if someone could throw me a bone, I'd be grateful. I've fixed the problem I was having with the image not displaying where I wanted it to, but I'm still having issues with the background color not changing, font size displaying different and when the cell is selected, it overlaps the cell separator.

Note: tried to include screen shots, but since I'm new SO wouldn't let me. I've provided a link where I've put the image of the selected cell that overlaps the separator below.

http://s1216.photobucket.com/albums/dd361/cabearsfan/?action=view&current=screenshot2.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are not using your nib reference of the UIImageView but you are using the default imageView property of the cell.

Comment: Ya, that fixed my image placement issue, but I still don't know why when selected the cell overlaps the separator. Or why the background color won't change.

Comment: Make sure your labels in the nib have clear color background. Or try changing the frame of the "bg" manually with CGRectMake() to debug further. Are you changing the height of the cell elsewhere? Selected view seems to have larger frame than the initial one.

Comment: Apparently I was setting it to a different height somewhere else in my program that I had forgotten about (DUH) :( Thanks for the quick slap upside the head. I also changed the background of the labels to clear, but the background color still isn't being changed to what I'm trying to change it to programatically.

Comment: Try changing "cell.backgroundView = bg;" to "cell.contentView = bg;"

Comment: Compiler error. -> "Object can not be set - either readonly property or no setter found"

Comment: Messed around with it a bit to get the syntax correct and cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; doesn't work either.

Comment: Also just tried adding - 

(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];  
}

to the code and still nothing. It's alright I got the program functioning correctly and thanks to your help formatted the way I want it. I'll mess with background color after I get more important issues tackled.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there is a mis-match between the imageview frame and the size of the image you're giving it.

After your setImage call, add this code to find out what's going on:

```
NSLog(@" imageView frame %f,%f, %f, %f",imageView.frame.origin.x,imageView.frame.origin.y,
    imageView.frame.size.width,imageView.frame.size.height);
NSLog(@" image  size %f x %f", image.size.width, image.size.height);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, right after I tried your code I noticed that I had linked the image to the wrong variable I had created, so instead of displayed where I was telling it to, it was just tossing it out there. Still not sure why when the cell is selected it overlaps the separator though.